# Using EntityManager#getReference() while deleting entities in JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, eclipselink

A transactional method in an EJB (using CMT) :

```
public boolean delete(Entity entity) {
    Entity managedEntity = entityManager.getReference(Entity.class, entity.getId());
    entityManager.remove(managedEntity);
    return !entityManager.contains(managedEntity);
}
```

Suppose that the specified entity has just been removed from the database. The client somehow happens to send the same detached entity once again in the next call to the `delete()` method. As such, the `getReference()` method should throw the `javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException`. This however, does not happen, since the `getReference()` method returns an uninitialized lazy proxy. The proxy instance will be returned as long as the proxy is available. A `DELETE` DML statement is issued unnecessarily and the client is notified wrongly by returning a true boolean value which is undesired for user experience.

This should not happen. In the next call to `delete()`, the `javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException` should be thrown, be adequately handled and the client should be warned against the non-existence of the entity.

I see the only way to do so is to use the `find()` method but it is unnecessary in this case because there is no need to access or modify the entity's state - loading entity's state from the database is not required. What is the way, only using the `find()` method?

Comment: Find wont go to the database if it exists in the cache, but if it doesn't exist in the cache, going to the db is the only way to know for sure.

Comment: What is the practical approach then?

Comment: Use find, or force an exception by calling flush.